# Landscape Question

Tags: landscape

I have set up a standalone instance of Landscape on my internal network.  My question is, when Landscape updates packages on a server, do they go out to the Internet to get them, or do they get them from the Landscape server?   I'm trying to determine whether I need to setup local repositories or not. It's not clear from the documentation what happens by default.

Comment: I think it should do that from the landscape server but perhaps their customer care contacts can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, managed computers use the apt sources lists. If you haven't changed them, it should pull packages from standard mirrors. If you want your managed computers to go through landscape, you can create a mirror, then associate a repository profile to override the default apt sources. You can find the related documentation here: https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/repositories

Comment: Thanks.  That's what it looks like to me as well.  By requirement, most servers on our network do not have internet access.  So, I am trying to find the best way to minimize the number of holes I need to poke in the firewall and make management easier.